# MySQL instance won't connect (AWS)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect to an AWS RDB (MySQL) via the MySQL Workbench and **cannot establish a connection**. The database is URL, name, and password are  correctly configured and actually worked a few days ago. I even checked the port with net stat and it says it is being used by MySQL (which is correct). Where is the issue?

(Pictures below)

Error:

[image]

MySQL verification:

[image]

Running instance verification (AWS):

[image]

MySQL WB config verification:

[image]

Public Accessibility:

[image]

Database security Groups:

[image]

Comment: Have you clicked on that "Configure Remote Management" button to verify that remote access is enabled?   Can you connect to it from an Amazon EC2 instance?  If so there is security turned on somewhere to block remote access.

Comment: @BrianC Public Accessibility is enabled (Just attached a picture), if that is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is from official docs:

```
By default, network access is turned off to a DB instance. You can specify rules in a security group that allows access from an IP address range, port, or EC2 security group. Once ingress rules are configured, the same rules apply to all DB instances that are associated with that security group. You can specify up to 20 rules in a security group.
```

Check your security group associated with mysql RDS under Connectivity & Security and add new inbound MySQL type TCP rule with your local Public IP address.

Comment: I added a security group that accepted all TCP connections on all ports from my IP and it still throws the error.

Comment: EDIT: I even extended it to ALL connections and it still threw.

Comment: have you checked that MySQL is running?

Comment: On my laptop? Yes, check the second picture above.

Comment: It says, in the DB Summary, that the engine behind the DB is MySQL and that the DB is up and running, I would imagine that means that MySQL is running on the DB

Comment: Can you try changing Type: MYSQL/Aurora and Source: 0.0.0.0/0, just to make sure  IP address is not wrong.

Comment: This worked, so why is it not accepting on the Accept All Connections setting?

Comment: Not sure but looks like purpose of "All" is different: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-other-instances